# ember js get form select after submit

Tags: ember.js

Tried to search some example with form select list but seems they always take value by using onchange function
http://balinterdi.com/2015/08/29/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20.html

However in my project I want something like this:

```
<form {{action "createBook" on="submit"}}>
  <p>{{input type='text' id='title' value=title}}</p>
  <p> <select name="lang" id="lang">
        <option value="">--Choose--</option>
        {{#each model.language as |lang|}}
          <option value="{{lang.url}}">{{lang.title}}</option>
        {{/each}}
      </select>
  </p>
</form>
```

In my controller I have:

```
actions:{
  createBook() {
    var title = this.get('title');  //This line works fine
    var lang = this.get('lang'); //This value from select isnt working at all
    //do stuffs ..
   },
}
```

What can i do so that i can get the value from select in createBook() actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the option value in select onchange and set value in from action handler,

```
<select onchange={{action "selectOption" value="target.value"}}>
    <option value="">--Choose--</option>
    {{#each model.language as |lang|}}
    <option value="{{lang.url}}">{{lang.title}}</option>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Actions,

```
actions: {
    selectOption: function(option) { 
        this.set("lang", option);
    }
}
```

Comment: this.set("lang", option) - this will set lang.url value, not the entire lang object. To get lang object, this.get('model.language').findBy('url',option)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<select {{action 'change' on='change'}}>
  {{#each content as |item|}}
    <option value="{{item.id}}">
    {{item.name}}
  </option>
{{/each}}
```

in onchange method and set the property of lang of selected item

```
actions: {
  createBook() {
    var title = this.get('title');  //This line works fine
    var lang = this.get('lang'); 
    console.log(lang, title);
  },

  change() {
    const selectedEl = this.$('select')[0];
    const selectedIndex = selectedEl.selectedIndex;
    const selectedValue = this.get('content')[selectedIndex];
    this.set('lang', selectedValue.id)
  }
}
```

Please check here[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/665ae862eb61a3bc81f553176aec3b80?openFiles=components.select-component.js%2C)

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.$ is not a function.

Comment: Where u r facing this issue?

Comment: @Nam if you put your form hbs code in component you wont get this.$ is not a function error. i guess only the component will have this.$ function.

Comment: I have met error with .$ sometimes in my project, looks like Im missing somethings to have this jquery works.
prudviraju : I did exactly like you did in controller
kumkanillam : also test in component but didnt work neither